# Highlight fullcalendar events that expands over multiple rows/columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar, ui-calendar

In my `Angular` `web app` I'm using [Angular UI Calendar](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/) combined with [Fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/) to show user's events.

In this when a user `click` on an event it gets highlighted, but this has a little downside to it as it is right now, because when an event expands over multiple rows (in `month` view) or multiple columns (in `week` view), it's not the hole event that get highlighted - Screenshot 1.

**Screenshot 1**
[image: Screenshot 1]

In the image we have `2. Event` that goes from 19. March to 21. March, but as you can see the only part that gets highlighted are the 19. and 20. March.

In `Screenshot 2` is how I really want it, so users don't get confused and maybe think that it's actually two events, instead of one event (which it would be in this case).

**Screenshot 2**
[image: Screenshot 2]

This is the part of my `controller` that adds the highlighting to the event.

**Controller**

```
$scope.alertOnEventClick = function(calEvent, jsEvent, view){
   $(".fc-state-highlight").removeClass("fc-state-highlight");
   angular.element(jsEvent.currentTarget).addClass("fc-state-highlight");
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fullcalendar 2.4 on hover demo (non-angular) https://jsfiddle.net/4kbLa4da/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultDate: '2016-03-01',
  events: [{
    start: '2016-03-01',
    end: '2016-03-05',
    title: 'Event 1'
  }, {
    start: '2016-03-06',
    end: '2016-03-15',
    title: 'Event 2',
    id: 3
  }],
  eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    // event._id gets auto-populated, either event.id or auto-generated value
    element.attr('data-id', event._id);
    toggleClass(event._id);
  },
  eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
    toggleClass(event._id);
  },
  eventMouseout: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
    toggleClass(event._id);
  }
});

function toggleClass(id) {
  /* Find all segments for the specific event and toggle a class */
  var $event = $('a.fc-event[data-id="' + id + '"]');
  $.each($event, function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('my-highlight');
  });
}
```

If you want it on event click: https://jsfiddle.net/4kbLa4da/2/

```
eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
    toggleClass(event._id);
  }
 /* ... */
/* And change toggleClass to turn it off first */
function toggleClass(id) {
  /* Find all segments for the specific event and toggle a class */
  var $event = $('a.fc-event[data-id="' + id + '"]');
  $('a.my-highlight').each(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('my-highlight');
  });
  $.each($event, function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('my-highlight');
  });
}
```

Comment: You sir are a genius, this is exactly what I was looking for, and it works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Good deal. As a heads up, the use of event._id is probably not best practice since it could change in fullcalendar's implementation in the future. The benefit is it allows it to work for events not given an explicit event.id

Comment: Since all my events have an id, I just changed event._id to event.id, but thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding _id custom